# How to create dataplot with logarithmic y-axis in PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I am trying to create some graph with a logarithmic y-axis in PSTricks. My Code Looks like this:

```
\psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=2cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-17)(8,1)
    \readdata[ignoreLines=1]{\DataSDEOne}{QR2-5x5-SDE1.dat}
    \psaxes[axesstyle=frame,Dx=2,ylogBase=10,Oy=-3](0,-3)(20,0)
    \dataplot[plotstyle=curve,linecolor=red]{\DataSDEOne}
\end{pspicture}
```

The data-file Looks like this:

```
Iteration   SDE1
0   0.918238878000000000000000000000
1   0.781163156000000000000000000000
2   0.683383048000000000000000000000
3   0.671932101000000000000000000000
4   0.559252858000000000000000000000
5   0.336966991000000000000000000000
6   0.193554908000000000000000000000
7   0.120545782000000000000000000000
8   0.089903891100000000000000000000
9   0.072258718300000000000000000000
10  0.041734408600000000000000000000
11  0.023705897900000000000000000000
12  0.000000003599741840000000000000
13  0.000000000000000434642119000000
14  0.000000000000000434642119000000
```

It seems to be that the dataplot does not use the scale given by the `\psaxes` command?
Another strange behaviour: If I increase `yunit` to 5cm, the whole graphic disappears.

[image: I wanted to create a Picture like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\psset{xunit=0.5cm,yunit=0.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-18)(15,1)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=frame,Dx=2,ylogBase=10,Dy=2,Oy=-18](0,-18)(15,0)
    \readdata[ignoreLines=1]{\DataSDEOne}{QR2-5x5-SDE1.dat}
    \pstScalePoints(1,1){}{ log }
    \listplot[linecolor=red]{\DataSDEOne}
\end{pspicture}
```

you want to show the y values as `log(y)`, the reason why you have to scale the points with `\pstScalePoints`